# Parcelable Model ArrayList pass activity A to activity B and get sub model ArrayList size it's return NullPointerException

Tags: android

**This is my Parcelable Model class**

```
public class BVCCategoryTemplateModel implements Parcelable {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("dir")
    private List<DirCategory> dir;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    protected BVCCategoryTemplateModel(Parcel in) {
        url = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();      
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(url);
        dest.writeString(name);     
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<BVCCategoryTemplateModel> CREATOR = new Creator<BVCCategoryTemplateModel>() {
        @Override
        public BVCCategoryTemplateModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BVCCategoryTemplateModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BVCCategoryTemplateModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BVCCategoryTemplateModel[size];
        }
    };

    public List<DirCategory> getDir() {
        return dir;
    }

    public void setDir(List<DirCategory> dir) {
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Keep
    public static class DirCategory implements Parcelable{
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("dir")
        private List<DirCategoryData> dir;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("url")
        private String url;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;

        protected DirCategory(Parcel in) {
            url = in.readString();
            name = in.readString();         
        }

        public static final Creator<DirCategory> CREATOR = new Creator<DirCategory>() {
            @Override
            public DirCategory createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new DirCategory(in);
            }

            @Override
            public DirCategory[] newArray(int size) {
                return new DirCategory[size];
            }
        };

        public List<DirCategoryData> getDir() {
            return dir;
        }

        public void setDir(List<DirCategoryData> dir) {
            this.dir = dir;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
            parcel.writeString(url);
            parcel.writeString(name);         
        }
    }
}
```

pass mode to another activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BVCTemplatePreviewBeforeEditActivity.class);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("category_data", new ArrayList<>(festivalCategoryTemplateModelsList));
                startActivity(intent);
```

another activity get a list like this

```
ArrayList<BVCCategoryTemplateModel> templateSubcategoryDataList = getIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("category_data");
```

get sub model class list `templateSubcategoryDataList.get(0).getDir().size()`
return `NullPointerException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at dfgdfg.sfgfdgd.dfgdfg.activity.BVCTemplatePreviewBeforeEditActivity.onCreate(EditActivity.java:103)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long time search, I found the issue

**Change**

```
protected BVCCategoryTemplateModel(Parcel in) {
        url = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();      
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(url);
        dest.writeString(name);     
    }
```

**To**

```
protected BVCCategoryTemplateModel(Parcel in) {
        url = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();  
        dir = new ArrayList<DirCategory>();
        in.readList(dir, DirCategory.class.getClassLoader());    
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(url);
        dest.writeString(name); 
        dest.writeList(dir);    
    }
```

I forgot to write my `List<DirCategory>` sub-model class to `writeToParcel()` method and read the list in Constructor, after editing the above code `NullPointerException` remove, and the code working file